# Get underlying type of any C++ dereferencable type

Tags: c++, pointers, templates

I have a function that creates a new object of the underlying type of `P`. Here `P` is a dereferencable type like a pointer or a smart pointer.

```cpp
template<typename P>
auto make_new()
```

For example, for pointers and smart pointers,

```cpp
struct A
{
    int a = 3;
};

A* a = make_new<A*>();
std::cout << a->a << std::endl;
delete a;

std::shared_ptr<A> b = make_new<std::shared_ptr<A>>();
std::cout << b->a << std::endl;
```

Now, for shared pointers, I would implement `make_new` as the following,

```cpp
template<typename P>
auto make_new()
{
    using Ptype = typename P::element_type;
    return P(new Ptype);
}
```

which doesn't work for pointers.

Now, something that works for both pointers and smart pointers,

```cpp
template<typename P>
auto make_new()
{
    using Ptype = typename std::remove_reference<decltype(*P())>::type;
    return P(new Ptype);
}
```

but doesn't work for `std::optional`.

Is there a canonical way of getting the underlying type of a de-referencable object?

I know that `*` and `->` can be overloaded to anything and there is no guarantee that constructor works like above, or makes sense to do.

Just want to know if there is a way and am not just finding it, or just doing something dumb.

Comment: Unrelated: If this is not for educational purposes, [consider using `std::make_shared`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/make_shared) and friends. If this is for educational purposes, you may find some neat tricks by looking at how `std::make_shared` is implemented.

Comment: Instead of `P()` in your `decltype` you can do [`std::declval<P>()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/declval). It works for non-default-constructible types.

Comment: Maybe through specialization? Though why don't you use something similar to `std::make_shared` or `std::make_unique` and *not* use pointer-types for the template argument? I'm also very curious about the underlying problem you try to solve? Why do you need this `make_new` function? Why do you need the template argument to be a dereferencable type?

Comment: And have you experimented with [`std::remove_pointer`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/remove_pointer)?

Comment: It very hard to explain the underlying problem. It is for an abstract computation meta-algorithm. Part of the problem is that it processes an element and can produce other elements of the same type.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude `std::remove_pointer` doesn't do anything to `shared_ptr`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Resolving the element type on both pointers and classes

**Target.** Our goal is to write a `using` template which takes a dereference-able type as input, and returns the element type.

```
template<class T>
using element_type_t = /* stuff */;
```

**Method.** We can use SFINAE to check if there's an `element_type` property, and if there's not, we fall back to using `std::remove_reference<decltype(*P())>()`.

```
// This is fine to use in an unevaluated context
template<class T>
T& reference_to(); 

// This one is the preferred one
template<class Container>
auto element_type(int) 
  -> typename Container::element_type;

// This one is the fallback if the preferred one doesn't work
template<class Container>
auto element_type(short) 
  -> typename std::remove_reference<decltype(*reference_to<Container>())>::type;
```

Once we have this function, we can write `element_type_t` by just getting the return type of `element_type`.

```
// We alias the return type
template<class T>
using element_type_t = decltype(element_type<T>(0));
```

**Why can't we always get the element_type by dereferencing it?** If you try to always get the value type using the `*` operator, that could cause issues with things like the iterator for `std::vector<bool>`, which returns an object that acts like a bool, but encapsulates bit manipulations. In these cases, the element type is different than the type returned by dereferencing it.

#### Determining if the constructor takes a pointer or a value

The reason your code fails with `std::optional` is because `std::optional`'s constructor takes the value itself, rather than a pointer to the value.
In order to determine which constructor we need, we use SFINAE again to make the determination.

```
// Base case - use new operator
template<class Container>
auto make_new_impl(int) 
    -> decltype(Container{new element_type_t<Container>})
{
    return Container{new element_type_t<Container>};
}

// Fallback case, where Container takes a value
template<class Container>
auto make_new_impl(long)
    -> decltype(Container{element_type_t<Container>()})
{
    return Container{element_type_t<Container>()};
}
```

Now, we can write `make_new` so that it calls `make_new_impl`:

```
template<class Container>
auto make_new() {
    return make_new_impl<Container>(0);
}
```

**Example.** We can now use `make_new` to make either `std::optional`, `std::shared_ptr`, or even a regular pointer.

```
#include <optional>
#include <memory>

int main() {
    // This works
    int* ptr = make_new<int*>(); 

    // This works too
    std::shared_ptr<int> s = make_new<std::shared_ptr<int>>();

    // This also works
    std::optional<int> o = make_new<std::optional<int>>(); 
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Absolutely brilliant. Wouldn't have occurred to me to do it this way.